# RestSharp и BadRequest

Tags: c#, post

Пытаюсь отправить некий **POST** запрос и все время в ответ получаю Bad Request.
В чем может быть проблема?

Код запроса:

```
private async void SellItem(string appid, string contextid, string assetid, string amount, string prise)

    {
        await GetJson(Properties.Settings.Default.myProfileURL + "/inventory/json/730/2");
        var client = new RestClient("http://steamcommunity.com")
        {
            UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0",
            FollowRedirects = true,
            CookieContainer = GenerateCookies(),
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };

        var request = new RestRequest("/market/sellitem/", Method.POST);
        foreach (var cookie in CookieContainer_ToList(client.CookieContainer))
        {
            if (cookie.Name == "sessionid")
            {
                request.AddParameter("sessionid", cookie.Value, ParameterType.GetOrPost);    
            }
        }
        request.AddParameter("appid", appid, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("contextid", contextid, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("assetid", _list.rgInventory[1].id, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("amount", amount, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("price", prise, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var response = client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        MessageBox.Show(response.Result.StatusCode.ToString()); //Bad Request
    }
```

Тело запроса:

```
POST /market/sellitem/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: steamcommunity.com
Cookie: sessionid=цензура; steamLogin=цензура; Steam_Language=russian
Content-Length: 95
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


sessionid=цензура&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid=2836967753&amount=1&price=8679
```

Если надо, то могу предоставить тело запроса "как в браузере".

**UPD**: Тело запроса "как в браузере":

```
    Host: steamcommunity.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Language: uk,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Referer: http://steamcommunity.com/id/kribetko/inventory/
    Content-Length: 95


sessionid=цензура&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid=2875087333&amount=1&price=8697
```

**UPD2**: Внезапно обнаружил, что для этого **POST** запроса используется "защищенное соединение" с шифрами `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`, хотя в js скрипте об этом ни слова. Я так полагаю, что в этом главная проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Вывовите до вашего кода:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: Аналогично - 400 Bad Request.